# Is it possible to override the default session notices?

Tags: templating, config, session

I couldn't find anything on here about this. Maybe I'm the only one, but for example when you log in there is a session notice with the message "Logged in.", but I want it to display something like "Good to see you" or something.

I can see the notices are set via `Craft::t()`, so I would assume they are translatable somehow, so can I do this through configuration files or a plugin init method or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you place a PHP file in `craft/translations` named after a locale ID and returning an array, those values will be used instead.

**craft/translations/en.php**

```
<?php

return array(
    'Logged in.' => 'Good to see you.',
);
```

Craft's own CP translation files can be found in `craft/app/translations`.

You can read more about it here: http://buildwithcraft.com/help/static-translations